# Pulse-shaping aparatus using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw the scheme for a pulse-shaping apparatus as in this 
[image: Pulse-shaping apparatus]

Any suggestion on how to   get started? I have checked the texamples web site wihtout success.

Until now, I have the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-0.05,-1.25) rectangle (0.25,1.5);
\draw (-3,0) ellipse (0.25cm and 1cm);
\draw (3,0) ellipse (0.25cm and 1cm);
\draw [rotate=45](-4.05,2.25) rectangle (-4.25,4.5);
%\draw [rotate=-30](-4.05,2.25) rectangle (-4.25,4.5);
\end{tikzpicture}{tikzpicture}
```

As you can see, I am not an skillful user of TikZ :). there is an easier way of define the figures for the gratings?  How can I represent the red and blue components and the input and output rays?

Comment: Which image do you mean exactly?

Comment: You ask for service "do-it-for-me"? Maybe you will succeed :-). Otherwise, take desired image, print it, and an paper define coordinates for each line and than draw it by simple `\draw (<coordinate 1>) -- (<coordinate 2>);`. When you will stack in this, show to us what you succeed to do. From there we can easy help you in TikZ issues ...

Comment: `\includegraphics{pulse-shaping-apparatus}`

Comment: I think the picture it's nice enough as it is. If the problem is about text, you can remove the text with an external program, include the picture as @HenriMenke suggested, and add the text with `tikz` (or something simpler). If you really want to do it with `tikz` (I would approve if the picture is as small as I see it on the screen), then it's all about print it, wear glasses, measure by means of a ruler, take note of relative positions of the various "interesting" point, and use a lot of `\draw (<coordinate 1>) -- (<coordinate 2>);` as @Zarko already pointed out.

Comment: Please make your code compilable as that is much more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodes may be easier. Here's a beginning which switches out your paths for (mostly) nodes using the `shapes.geometric` library for the lenses.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, every node/.append style={draw}]
  \node (m) [minimum width=3mm, minimum height=30mm, inner color=blue!50!black!50, outer color=blue!50!black] {};
  \draw [line width=.5mm, gray] ([xshift=-65mm]m.west) coordinate (l1) -- ([yshift=-30mm,xshift=10mm]m.south east) coordinate [pos=.3] (l2) coordinate (l3);
  \draw [line width=.5mm, gray] ([xshift=65mm]m.east) coordinate (r1) -- ([yshift=-30mm,xshift=-10mm]m.south west) coordinate [pos=.3] (r2) coordinate (r3);
  \node (ll) [anchor=south, ellipse, minimum height=30mm, minimum width=5mm, fill=blue!25!gray, fill opacity=.025] at (l2) {};
  \node (lr) [anchor=south, ellipse, minimum height=30mm, minimum width=5mm, fill=blue!25!gray, fill opacity=.025] at (r2) {};
  \node [rotate=-45, anchor=north, minimum height=2mm, minimum width=20mm, fill=yellow!25] at (l1) {};
  \node [rotate=45, anchor=north, minimum height=2mm, minimum width=20mm, fill=yellow!25] at (r1) {};
  \foreach \i/\m in {l/west,r/east}
  \foreach \j/\k in {75/blue,-75/red}
  \draw [blend mode=overlay, fill=\k] (\i1) -- (l\i.{\j+5}) -- (m.\m |- l\i.\j) -- (l\i.{\j-5}) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: node-based]

Extensions, enhancements and entanglements are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: When I paste  the code in your answer  within a beamer slide,  the red and blue shifting disappears from the image.  Do you know why?

Comment: Well, you didn't mention Beamer. Try removing the blend mode specification. I'm guessing Beamer won't like that because it does some complicated things with colours itself.

Comment: You can use the `backgrounds` library to put the fills behind the lenses. Or you can redraw the lenses after adding the red and blue fills. You might want to skip filling the lenses in the first case (although the fill is very subtle so it probably won't much matter).

Comment: Thanks  again, a quick solution is change the last line to `\draw [ mode=overlay, fill=\k, opacity=0.7 ] (\i1) -- (l\i.{\j+5}) -- (m.\m |- l\i.\j) -- (l\i.{\j-5}) -- cycle;`

Comment: It depends how much of a perfectionist you are ;).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42833/discussion-between-ruben-dario-guerrero-and-cfr).

Comment: Hi, Trying to add the labels using \node[yshift=18mm,xshift=0mm] at (m) {\footnotesize Modulator};  the label is withing a box, how can I avoid it?

Comment: Add `draw=none` or remove the `draw` from the `every node` and add manually when wanted. Labels did not feature in your MWE so I did what was most efficient for the diagram without them.